# Prime ideals of $F[x,y]/(x^2+y^2+1)$, where $F=\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: commutative-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I want to find the prime ideals of $R=F[x,y]/(x^2+y^2+1)$, where $F=\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$.

Ok, $(x^2+y^2+1)$ is irreducible, then $(0)$ is a prime ideal in $R$. Also any other prime in $R$ must be prime in $F[x,y]$ and contain $(x^2+y^2+1)$; hence it won't be generated by a single irreducible polynomial. Then I have the ideals on the form $(q(x), f(x,y))$ left, where $q$ is irreducible in $F[x]$ and $f$ is irreducible in $F[x,y]/(q(x))$.

> Which of them contains $(x^2+y^2+1)$?

I also tried to build a isomorphism $\varphi :R\rightarrow F[\sin (t)i, \cos (t)i]$ and see it like a two variable polynomial ring over $F$. Didn't work...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: $(x-i,y)$ for $F=\Bbb C$ and $(x^2+1,y)$ for $F=\Bbb R$ are two of the ideals you're looking for.

Comment: In fact, the non-zero prime ideals of $R$ correspond to maximal ideals of $F[x,y]$ containing $x^2+y^2+1$. The case $F=\mathbb C$ is easily enough: these are of the form $(x-a,y-b)$ with $a^2+b^2+1=0$. For $F=\mathbb R$ the things are a little more complicated.

Comment: Thanks, your comments helped with the $F=\mathbb{C}$ case . For $\mathbb{R}$ I think I can find the maximals of $F[x,y]$, thanks!!!